# Is it possible to override this virtual method in C++?

Tags: c++, io, serial-port

In this program I'm trying to read data from a serial port but the data being read form the port is not in a format I like (comes out in large chunks). So I want to override how ReadBytes works.

```
BSTR buffer_bstr;
hr = pCom->ReadBytes( &buffer_bstr );
```

So ReadBytes is found in a library header called AComport.h made by the company ActiveXperts. When I go to the declaration of ReadBytes it is this

```
    virtual /* [helpstring][id] */ HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE ReadBytes( 
        /* [retval][out] */ BSTR *__MIDL__IComPort0001) = 0;
```

What is this saying? I was looking for an implementation of ReadBytes so that I could change things around but all I see is this. What does it mean?

Comment: You could override it by deriving your own class and providing your own implementation of the function, but without the actual source code you're going to have to do everything from scratch.

Comment: How is the source code hidden? Just wondering..

Comment: Most likely all you have is a .DLL that implements the COM object.

Comment: Any reason why you do not use QtSerialPort for serial port handling??

Comment: Well, until now I've never head of QtSerialPort. I'm using this because I'm building off of someone's previous work. Why is Qt better than COM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a "real" C++ function, but it's a member function on a COM object that is presented as a C++ wrapper. Unless you implement an object that implements the same COM interface, you can't easily override or overload this function.